# DocumentDB find deep key:value

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, nosql

in MongoDB I can perform a find on any deep level key like

```
collection.find('persons.age': 12)
```

Is a similar thing possible with document DB? I have tried something like the following which fails with: code":"BadRequest" - could not be resolved.

```
query: "SELECT * FROM root WHERE person.age = 12"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reference the collection from the `FROM` clause.

Note: Since you are issuing queries directly to a collection, you can use any arbitrary value for the name. However, you must re-use whatever value you chose in the other clauses because it serves as a reference point for projections and predicates (in the SELECT and WHERE clause).

If your document's schema resembles:

```
{
    person: {
        age: 39
    }
}
```

You can query documents by age using:

```
SELECT *
FROM root
WHERE root.person.age = 39
```

Or if your document's schema resembles:

```
{
    age: 39
}
```

You can query documents by age using:

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE person.age = 39
```